# Can't get bootstrap navigation toggler to work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get the following lines to work using bootstrap, but I'm facing a difficulty in which  when I click on the toggler nothing appears. The button does appear to notice when I'm hovering on it and clicking but nothing appears. I'm using the same example as in the official following page:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

If someone can figure out the problem help would be greatly appreciated.

I have made sure that the problem isn't connected to my CDN links and I hope I checked for all possible typo mistakes.

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top navbar-default" id="sideNav">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
        <span class="d-block d-lg-none">Guy</span>
        <span class="d-none d-lg-block">
            <img class="img-fluid img-profile mx-auto mb-4" src="img/profile.jpeg" alt="">
        </span>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#awards">Curriculum Vitae</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#experience">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#education">Publications</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, did you include popper JS?

Comment: I have added the following line: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using? ... It says 5.1 but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code may be you not using `CDN` in correct format.**

**Replace**:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

**With**:

```
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top navbar-default" id="sideNav">
<a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
    <span class="d-block d-lg-none">Guy</span>
    <span class="d-none d-lg-block">
        <img class="img-fluid img-profile mx-auto mb-4" src="img/profile.jpeg" alt="">
    </span>
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#awards">Curriculum Vitae</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#experience">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#education">Publications</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</nav>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Your `Style CDN` is inside head tag and your `script CDN` is after all the html code.

**Let me know if this will work for you**.

Comment: I can see that your code is working but it doesn't seems like I manage to get mine to work which is really weird.

Comment: Now check , I updated my source code now it's your code and it's working now..

Comment: Amazing! What did you change? I just copied you'r nav tag and it works. So it wasn't the cdn stuff.

Comment: see what I changed. I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you very much, now I'm going to learn what is data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target means.